USB 2.0 Full-speed differential impedance
The USB 2.0 Full-speed specifications, and numerous other sources on the internet list a signal differential impedance of 90 ohms. However, most designs use a pair of 22 ohm termination resistors on the D+ and D- lines, also recommending that traces be kept short.
The following is from the USB-IF website's documentation for 2.0 device impedance, noting that CM impedance must be 30 ohms with a differential impedance of 90.

Why is an impedance of 90 ohms used for USB when most designs use a 22 ohm resistor, and traces are kept intentionally short?(i.e. less resistance and signal loss).

In short, the external resistors are used to match the output impedance of the chip which is too small to the required driver impedance of the wire, Zdrv.
It also does not mean that the wire must be driven with 90 ohm differential impedance or that it is even terminated with 90 ohms. Clearly, it isn't terminated and the Zdrv requirement of single wire being driven at 28 to 44 ohms means that at the extreme end of the range, at 44 ohms, the cable is driven at most 88 ohms. The 90 ohms differential and 30 ohms common mode is just the impedance of the cabling. It's not even stated what would be the parameters of the PCB tracks, as very often 90 ohms is not used but something a bit less like 85 for lower losses.
The chips/MCUs that require external resistors have very strong IO structures as they are intended to be used as high speed GPIO intended to drive small loads and fast buses on PCB, so the IO stage strength is not tunable and does not have a mode intended to drive an USB bus.
As these IO drivers are too strong, i.e. have lower impedance, adding a series resistor brings up the impedance higher so it is within the specification required to drive the cable, 28 to 44 ohms in total for each pin, which equals 56 to 88 ohms differential impedance.
Which is about right, a generic CMOS output could have about 22 ohms of output impedance and 22 ohm external resistor matches it to 44 ohms. Sometimes 27 ohm resistors are seen too.
Like your quote says, the tolerance range for USB chip is quite large.
The additional resistors also double as limiting the slew rate and bandwidth, allow for better ESD handling and all other sorts of things.
In every high speed design, the PCB traces are told to be kept short. Also due to losses but for impedance matching reasons. If you have very short traces you might not need to consider a 12 Mbps USB as a transmission line at all so you can just wire your connector throgh resistors to IC. If the PCB traces are long, then the problem is, what impedance you should design it for. The cable ending up with connector is already an impedance discontinuity and then the cable impedance transitions into PCB wiring impedance. And impedance discontinuities are always a problem. So better to have very short PCB tracks.
